# How could I define methods on an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**UPDATE:**

I've put this in my `person` class

```
  has_many :things, :dependent => :destroy do 
    def [](kind)
      where("kind = ?", kind.to_s)
    end
  end
```

but when I invoke `<Person Instance>.things[:table]`, I get this error:

```
undefined method `where' for #<Class:0x111dc3ba8>
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I have a `person`, who `has_many` `things`.
I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
<Person Instance>.things[:table]
```

that would be defined similar to

```
def things[](arg)
    self.things.find(:first, :conditions => ["kind = ?", arg.to_s])
end
```

currently, that method gives me this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting '\n' or ';'
```

So, how do I properly define things[]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for are called association extensions in rails.
[Read about it here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Association+extensions)

Your implementation might look something like:

```
has_many :things do
  def [](kind)
    where(:kind => kind)
  end
end
```

Comment: so, i'd put `def [](args)` in a module, and have `:has_many => :things, :extend => MyModule`?

Comment: You could do the module approach, or right in line as in the example.

Comment: ooo. i see how that makes sense now. Will report back in a bit.

Comment: I got undefined method, `where` I'm using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.14, does that matter? i'll update my question.

Comment: Oh, yes.  Sorry I wasn't aware of the version and tend to assume v3.  You'd want to use the same `find` method you had in your original.  I think, otherwise, that associations extension have been defined similarly for a very long time.

Comment: what's the scope of the [] method? do I need to do self.things.find? or just find?

Comment: It's a good question.  In Rails 3 you have access to the class methods, although I don't think it's as simple as being in the class scope (probably some kind of specially built association scope, perhaps with proxied methods, but you'd have to look at the source)  Rails 2.3 was quite a long time ago and I don't remember how it worked, but you could always check the same sourcefile for that version and probably find an explanation.

Comment: it seems to be relative to person.things, =D

Answer (score -1):

I think `[]` are not allowed in method names...
You could just skip them in your method name, but then your association method would be overwritten/replaced, if you've set up your assocations properly.

I'd do something like this:

```
# in your Person model
def things_of_kind(kind)
  self.things.find(:first, :conditions => ["kind = ?", arg.to_s]
end

# then you could call
<PersonInstance>.things_of_kind(:table)
```

Alternatively there are [association extensions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Association+extensions) which use this technique but in the proper place.
And there are also [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes), which can be helpful.

Comment: `[]` and `[]=` are valid ruby methods.  You see them all over actually.

Comment: That's true... Somehow I thought this is wrong. Too many languages juggling in my head :) Thanks for the correction!

Comment: It is very odd looking.  I always find myself wanting to prefix them with a `:` or something, but it just works.